# How to show track and exist files with git ls-files

Tags: git

Let's assume that I add a file to repository, commit it and then delete it (but not commit again).

So. git ls-files will show it.
But I don't want to see it because this file don't exist in the working tree.

Is there any combination to achieve it ?

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: "*…add a file to repository, commit it and then delete it (but not commit again) … this file don't exist in the repository.*" Not true. The file exists in the repository and the index (cache). It doesn't exits in the working tree.

Comment: Got it but I still have the same question just change repository to working tree. @phd

Comment: To see the files in the working tree just do the regular OS command: `ls` or `dir`.

Comment: I want to see only files in the repository and working tree at the same time. @rodrigo

Comment: @Alex I don't think `git ls-files` can do that. It can list deleted files, but I don't know any way to list everything except deleted.

Answer (score 1):

`git ls-files` doesn't care about commits, it cares about the index and its relation to the work tree.

You can ask it for files listed in the index that have been deleted in the work tree, but the reverse is unusual enough no one's taught it to do that yet. You can get the effect with

```
comm -3 <(git ls-files) <(git ls-files -d)
```

"show me staged files that exist only in the index, not in both lists, not in the second, in-the-index-but-deleted list".

Answer (score 0):

```
git diff --diff-filter=D --name-only @
```

returns the deleted files.

```
git ls-files . ':!'"$(git diff --diff-filter=D --name-only @)"
```

uses [exclude pattern](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-exclude) to exclude the file.

That doesn't work if there're more than one deleted file. To construct a list of excludes run a loop over deleted files:

```
git ls-files . $(for f in $(git diff --diff-filter=D --name-only @); do echo ':!'"$f"; done)
```